# Border-collapse and colspan in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a simple example table with 3 rows and 5 columns styled with a `border-collapse: collapse` border.

The problem here is that I have a `colspan=4` `td` in the second row, with IE11 (11.0.9600.17691) not showing the right border of that row.

You can see this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/j6u026oz/2/

I've tried putting an extra right border to the `tr` and `th` elements but it doesn't work.

Adding an extra `th` next to the `colspan=4` element could solve this issue but I'd prefer to solve this problem with CSS if it's possible, as touching the HTML structure would imply a lot of changes in the project I'm working in.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the extra column by CSS, using `::after` pseudo-element:

**[Updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/j6u026oz/4/)**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tbody > tr:first-child:after {
  content: "";
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">colspan4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td1</td>
      <td>td2</td>
      <td>td3</td>
      <td>td4</td>
      <td>td5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

from your css file.

use the code as below

```
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Hi! The problem is that collapse border is a requirement :(

Answer (score 0):

Use "outline" instead of "border".

```
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: 1px solid red;    /* ---- this lil' guy ---- */
}
```